# combolistbox.Item.Add(FileInfo) inconsistent?

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox, fileinfo

I am having a bit of trouble with this method.

When I loop through the FileInfo type objects in dragDropFiles and add each individually to the CLB I get the FullName property (full path to file, which is what I need) returned when the item is checked.
However with the hotFolderFiles instead of the path it gives me just the file name.

I do not understand this because they are adding the same object type in the same manner.

(I also tried getting the FileInfo for hot folder files using the DirectoryInfo instead of my Dictionary with same results)

Why is this behavior inconsistent?
(and how can I get it to return the fileInfo fullName instead of Name?)

```
    public frmFilesFound(string hotFolderPath, Dictionary<string, FileInfo> dragDropFiles, Dictionary<string, FileInfo> hotFolderFiles, bool ReadOnly)
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            readOnly = ReadOnly;

            btnSelectAll.Visible = true;
            clbSelectFilesFound.Visible = true;
            clbSelectFilesFound.FormattingEnabled = true;
            clbSelectFilesFound.Format += (s, e) => { e.Value = string.Format("{0}", ((FileInfo)e.ListItem).Name); };


            foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in dragDropFiles.Values)
            {
                if (!clbSelectFilesFound.Items.Contains(fileInfo))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // If file not already present, add it to listbox
                        clbSelectFilesFound.Items.Add(fileInfo);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message); }
                }
            }
            //intended to be hot folder path
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(hotFolderPath))
            {
                DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(hotFolderPath);

                foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in dirInfo.GetFiles())
                //foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in hotFolderFiles.Values)
                {
                    if (!clbSelectFilesFound.Items.Contains(fileInfo))
                    {
                            try
                            {
                                clbSelectFilesFound.Items.Add(fileInfo);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message); }
                    }
                }
            }
            lblDisplayedSelectMessage.Text = "More than one file is waiting.  Please select the files you would like to use.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because the DirectoryInfo.GetFiles method only fills in the name of the file, and not the full path.

Try this formatter if you only want to show the name of the file in all cases:

`clbSelectFilesFound.Format += (s, e) => {
e.Value = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(((FileInfo)e.ListItem).Name);
};`

Comment: I get the same result when I use my dictionary, see commented out line beneath, instead of `GetFiles()`.
However the dictionary manner works correctly within the first ForEach loop.
My formatting is working as intended.

Comment: Yes, but we don't see where the dragDropFiles and hotFolderFiles come from. So I only can suggest this work-around

Comment: I don't understand why you think this would be a work around, this has exactly the same affect as my existing Formatter. (and my question wasn't about formatting)
And you can see that the dragDropFiles and hotFolderFiles are coming from the constructor...

Comment: I see, it's the code in your Checked handler that doesn't do what you want. Does it mather which path you pass as hotFolderPath? When I test this with "c:\\windows" I get full paths when getting the FullName property

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just always Add(fileInfo.FullName) ?

Comment: That's just the beauty of a combobox, you can add objects to it. Otherwise, f.e. the property SelectedItem would have no use.

Comment: Then set it's data member filter to "FullName", or tag the item with the fileInfo itself, for future reference.

Comment: I'm adding the object because I want to display the file Name in the comboListBox but I want to use the FullName from the selection results.

Comment: oh you want the other way around, I will modify my answer :)